# Word for focusing on what you do not have?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I would say “practicing gratitude” to convey the thought of focusing on what one has in life and ruminating on little things in a positive way, the glass half full. What would be the opposite word or phrase for when one habitually focuses on what they do not have. Not necessarily in relation to someone else as in envy or jealousy.

**Edit:**

As suggested in the comments, here’s some clarification:

Ingratitude just implies a lack of gratitude, I think. I’m looking for the other side of the coin. Someone who would practice gratitude might take note of the small things in life, even keep a gratitude journal, or look for ways to express such to a friend. But I’m looking for a word that describes someone who focuses on what’s missing, as if the person is almost making a list of what he doesn’t have and complaining or ruminating over that.

Comment: Hello, John, and welcome to EL&U. You need to flesh this out a bit: include some research into words that might come close, and please provide a sample sentence showing the usage of the target language.

Comment: Two words: negative outlook.

Comment: You use 'gratitude' in a way that doesn't directly invoke a benefactor. Can't 'ingratitude' be used the same way?

Comment: "Pessimistic" almost works, I think.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ingratitude just implies a lack of gratitude, I think. I’m looking for the other side of the coin. Someone who would practice gratitude might take note of the small things in life, even keep a gratitude journal, or look for ways to express such to a friend. But I’m looking for a word that describes someone who focuses on what’s missing, as if the person is almost making a list of what he doesn’t have and complaining or ruminating over that.

Comment: The glass is always half-empty. For the optimist, half-filled. For the realist, the glass is the wrong size.

Comment: @Xanne For Mr Spock, the glass is 49.3854935% empty.

Comment: "Influencer," in the social media context?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe **envy**

> **envy** NOUN
>   1A feeling of discontented or resentful longing aroused by someone else's possessions, qualities, or luck.
>   [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/envy)

Answer (score 1):

**Negativity**

A person who focuses on the least attractive or desirable areas in their life is expressing negativity.

https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/negativity

Answer (score 0):

**Wishful thinking.**

Definition of "wishful thinking"
: the attribution of reality to what one wishes to be true or the tenuous justification of what one wants to believe [*M-W*]

*Doris's dream vacation home in Hawaii was just wishful thinking.*

Answer (score 0):

The phrase that came to mind was [**negative Nancy**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/negative_Nancy#English).

> A person who is considered excessively and disagreeably pessimistic.

Other names beginning with N are sometimes substituted, such as Nelly or Ned.